# Xfsdump failed to get bulkstat information for root inode

Tags: linux, centos

I use **xfsdump** to make a dump from my CentOS server, but it occurs this error, how can I fix it?

```
[root@my_server ~]# xfsdump - /dev/vda2
xfsdump: using file dump (drive_simple) strategy
xfsdump: version 3.0.4 (dump format 3.0) - Running single-threaded
xfsdump: unable to determine uuid of fs mounted at /: Inappropriate ioctl for device
xfsdump: level 0 dump of my_server:/
xfsdump: dump date: Tue Jul 21 15:42:16 2020
xfsdump: session id: aeecf825-9dce-477f-b383-549cb7cf980b
xfsdump: session label: ""
xfsdump: ERROR: failed to get bulkstat information for root inode
xfsdump: Dump Status: ERROR
```

And this is the list of system disks:

```
[root@my_server ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda2        16G  3.5G   12G  24% /
tmpfs           939M     0  939M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/vdb1        99G  5.9G   88G   7% /var/my_dir
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the type of it is the right (xfs) so try to run

```
blkid
```

if it's **ext*** then try to use **dump** instead of **xfs**